# getting error while writing pyspark dataframe to snowflake table [snowflake-cloud-data-platform]

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am reading data from snowflake using pyspark. I performed some transformations on top of it. I am now trying to write the transformed data back to snowflake but am getting some error when trying to do that. I am unable to find much documentation on this one. If you have overcome this issue please share what i am missing. Thanks in advance.

```
pyspark --> 2.3.2
python --> 3.6
snowflake spark connector --> spark-snowflake_2.11-2.7.0-spark_2.4.jar
snowflake jdbc --> snowflake-jdbc-3.12.9.jar
```

NOTE: am using an user with same role with which the DB, Schema, table was created. SYSADMIN

```
    # set options for write:
    sfOptionswrite = {
    "sfURL" : "xxxxxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com",
    "sfUser" : "xxxxx",
    "sfPassword" : getpass.getpass(prompt='Enter your password: '),
    "sfDatabase" : "DB",
    "sfSchema" : "SCHEMA",
    "sfWarehouse" : "WH_NAME",
    "sfRole" : "SYSADMIN"
    }
    
    # write transformed dataframe df to snowflake:
    
    df.write.format('net.snowflake.spark.snowflake')\
    .options(**sfOptionswrite)\
    .option('dbtable', 'TABLE_NM')\
    .mode('overwrite')\
    .save()
```

ERROR:

Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.InternalS3Storage; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7958783596366368645, local class serialVersionUID = -6090755107217034776

Answer (score 0):

How are you invoking your spark code ? Are you using spark-submit ? Also do you have all the required packages ?

This might be incompatible jars also.

Please check the below link if that helps ?

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00007b2iXx/spark-connector-error-dfshow-

Kindly let me know.

Comment: hi @hopeIsTheOnlyWeapon thanks for your response. Am able to connect to snowflake (SF) and read the SF table. Am not aware if version compatibility can be an issue for write alone. Am performing this via Jupyter notebook by initializing SparkSession.

Comment: i tried the jar files mentioned in the url you shared. But still am getting the same error Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.io.InternalS3Storage; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7958783596366368645, local class serialVersionUID = -6090755107217034776